# Control + Space isn't working on unity project on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have done Assets create c# script from Unity, then opened the project from visual studio 2015, it shows the empty file but I can't find recomendations of how to autocomplete instructions.

I usually do cntr + space on c++ with vs but now it inserts me an empty space, nothing else. I went to tools options, keyboard and put cntr + space for completeWord to general (all languages) but isn't working. Tried with any combination of commands but didn't work too.

---

EDIT:
I don't even have c# as a language on visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to have C# installed as a supported language in VS before you can do anything with it. The feature you want is called *IntelliSense* and it pre-compiles your code in the background while you write. The types and members are determined through reflection, so VS actually needs compiled code to reflect on. It is not the same as some text editors, which have a vocabulary of common words.

This the background compilation is impossible without C# being installed in VS.

Comment: how to install it? I have it on visual studio 2010 but it gives me an error while opening unity project:
"one or several projects of solution didn't load correctly.

Comment: That's not easy to say. Normally this happens when the version of a project is not compatible with VS. But I use Unity 3D and VS2010 without any problems. On Linux I use MonoDevelop and I can open the solutions on both platforms. I don't know what is happening there, you should post some more details. Can you create a C# solution/project from scratch?

Comment: I'm creating a c# solution from scratch, it opens on vs2015 but doesn't on vs2010, but vs2010 has c# and vs2015 hasn't c#...

Comment: Those solution/project files are not compatible. There are differences between VS2010 and VS2015. VS2015 is retro-compatible while VS2010 couldn't possible be compatible to the unknown future VS2015. Even if C# is not on VS2015 it looks like it can handle that stuff. Probably it won't compile but at least it can be used as an IDE. Try creating the project in VS2010. Compare the *.sln and *.proj files to see the differences.

Comment: solved for 2010 downloading: tools for unity on vs 2010

Comment: hi @DanielRocaLopez if you solved the problem, be sure to TICK this answer.  cheers